# Do HTTPCookieStorage.shared() and WKWebsiteDataStore.default() share cookies?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, wkwebview, nshttpcookiestorage

I have a web view in my app whose cookies are stored automatically in WKWebsiteDataStore.default(). When I logout I delete these cookies using :

```
[[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes completionHandler:^(NSArray<WKWebsiteDataRecord *> * _Nonnull records) {
    [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes forDataRecords:records completionHandler:^{}];
}];
```

But when I login again the WKWebsiteDataStore is having same old cookies. Through iteration I checked that these cookies are stored in `HTTPCookieStorage.shared` also and `WKWebsiteDataStore` probably uses them.

I want to know what's the dependency between these two. Should I clear cookies in both WKWebsiteDataStore and HTTPCookieStorage?